# how to add security context to flask?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, flask

I was trying to add a security context to a simple flask application

```
import flask
import ssl

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>THIS IS HOME</h1>"


ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ctx.load_cert_chain('crt-key-crs/download-system.crt', 'crt-key-crs/download-system.key')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, ssl_context=ctx)
```

and when running it after typing the pass phrase the following error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask-test.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, ssl_context=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 710, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in inner
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 486, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 425, in __init__
    self.socket = tsafe.Connection(ssl_context, self.socket)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/tsafe.py", line 11, in __init__
    self._ssl_conn = apply(_ssl.Connection, args)
NameError: name 'apply' is not defined
```

Then I found in the docs that apply(function, *args, **kwargs) was replaced by function(*args, **kwargs) so I went to the file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/tsafe.py` and manually modified that line and when running again the following error came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask-test.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, ssl_context=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 710, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in inner
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 486, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 425, in __init__
    self.socket = tsafe.Connection(ssl_context, self.socket)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/tsafe.py", line 11, in __init__
    self._ssl_conn = _ssl.Connection(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 804, in __init__
    raise TypeError("context must be a Context instance")
TypeError: context must be a Context instance
```

After this and knowing that apply was completely removed from python3.x I run my application with python2.7.9 to check if I did something wrong when modifying that line and apparently I didn't because the same error happened again. So what do I need to do or change in my code in order to use a security context with my flask application? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching and testing a lot I found that the code is alright, the problem was the version of the Werkzeug server. I upgraded with `sudo pip3 install Werkzeug --upgrade` and now it's working fine.

Comment: In the Werkzeug changelog comments for 0.10.0 dated January 30th 2015 : "- Use stdlib ``ssl`` module instead of ``OpenSSL`` for the builtin server
  (issue ``#434``). This means that OpenSSL contexts are not supported anymore,
  but instead ``ssl.SSLContext`` from the stdlib."  So to use python stdlib ssl you need Werkzeug version 0.10.0 or greater